# Matching ImageView height to adjacent EditTexts and maintaining image proportions

Tags: android, android-edittext, imageview, android-linearlayout

In my Linear I have an ImageView and 2 EditText fields adjacent to it. I want the image to match the height of both EditTexts and scale proportionally. My images in resources are standard sizes: 144*144, 96*96 etc... This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_trip_dates_icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_new_trip_name"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_new_trip_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ico_add_contact"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_trip_dates"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_new_trip_start_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Start date"
            android:inputType="date" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_new_trip_end_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="End date"
            android:inputType="date" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I make the image itself be larger and match the height of both text fields? I don't mind if the EditText fields will be smaller in width and there will be a little gap between them.

Comment: you can use relative layout and alignTop first edittext and alignBottom second edittext for the imageView play with the scaletype property for more controls

Answer (score 0):

For the ImageView you can use android:adjustViewBounds to maintain ratio :D

Hope it helps.

Comment: It didn't really work... But for some reason when I made the largest images 288*288 instead of 144*144 - everything worked just fine. Even without `adjustViewBounds`.